# Joining entries with the same parameters in list C#

Tags: c#, .net

Let's say I have the following list

```
List<Invoice> InvoiceList

[0]
   AdvertiserCustomerID = "Generic Brand"
   GrossAmount = 1452
[1]
   AdvertiserCustomerID = "Generic Brand"
   GrossAmount = 4325
[2]
   AdvertiserCustomerID = "Generic Brand"
   GrossAmount = 2
[3]
   AdvertiserCustomerID = "Generic Brand 2"
   GrossAmount = 9211
```

What would be the easiest way of combining the brands with the same AdvertiserCustomerID into one entry, and compute the sum of the GrossAmount? So the final list would look like this:

```
List<Invoice> InvoiceList

[0]
   AdvertiserCustomerID = "Generic Brand"
   GrossAmount = 5779
[1]
   AdvertiserCustomerID = "Generic Brand 2"
   GrossAmount = 9211
```

I accomplished this by creating a new list and checking with FindIndex towards the AdvertiserCustomerID, but I'm wondering if there's an easier way of doing this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
var result = InvoiceList
     .GroupBy(m => m.AdvertiserCustomerId)
     .Select(group => new Invoice {
                AdvertiserCustomerID = group.Key,
                GrossAmount = group.Sum(g => g.GrossAmount)
                }
     );
```

(in your example, you don't multiply, you sum)

this will give you an `IEnumerable<Invoice>`, you can add a `.ToList()` at the end to enumerate.